# bug in google drive SDK JS api (TypeError: Cannot read property 'sl' of undefined)

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-api-js-client

A few weeks ago we started noticing strange errors from the google client API or google drive JS api (not sure which, the URL reference is below), they have increased in frequency over the last few days

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'sl' of undefined
```

This seems to be affecting windows Chrome mostly - a typical example of the user agent from our error logs is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31)
```

from what I could see, the only line with .sl is this:

```
if(!this.b.headers.Authorization){var f=(0,_.Hx)(_.p,_.p);f&&f[_.Ak.pl.sl]&&(c=f[_.Ak.pl.sl].split(/\w+/))}
```

this comes from

```
https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.uSTvEdNXb7o.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=UQ/rs=AItRSTOm1KS5pZVEepZkn9qQJeuQZC_Qjw/cb=gapi.loaded_0
```

I know this is intentionally cryptic, so it's beyond me to suggest how to fix it, but I would appreciate if someone looks into this as the frequency seems to be increasing. Perhaps a guard around _Ak.pl to check if it's not null before executing .sl ?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Is there any solution available? This is something related to the SDK provided. I am only following the samples given in the documents.

Comment: we did some more investigation and the problem seems to be related to session timeout. a workaround is to check if the gapi auth token is empty and if so try to call auth again before calling any other function.

Comment: Found the solution and the problem seems to be because of the authorize settings. The API seems to be not working with the settings "offline".

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve the problem which was reported. The issue is due to the authorize settings. Some settings seems to be not working for the app. Now the app works with following settings:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
```

Previously the app was configured to run offline.

*Note: In the code, clientId and scopes are variables, handleAuthResult is an associated function.*